# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object 2

Tags: java, c#, android, json, serialization

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like `integer`, not a collection type like an `Array` or `List<T>`) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. `JsonObjectAttribute` can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

**Delivery.java :**

```
class Delivery
{
    public List<Deliveries> delivery { get; set; }
}
class Deliveries
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public DateDetails delivery_date { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime update_at { get; set; }
    public int driver_id { get; set; }
    public int vehicle_id { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetails> Orders { get; set; }
    public InformationDetails driver { get; set; }   
    public Vehicle vehicle { get; set; }
}
class Vehicle
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string plate_number { get; set; }
    public double max_cargo_weight { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime update_at { get; set; }
}
class DateDetails
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int timezone_type { get; set; }
    public string timezone { get; set; }
}

class OrderDetails
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string or_number { get; set; }
    public DateDetails or_date { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
    public int customer_id { get; set; }
    public int delivery_id { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public InformationDetails customer { get; set; }

}

class InformationDetails
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string middle_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string avatar { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime update_at { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
}
```

**JSON Data:**

```
"deliveries":[  
  {  
     "id":1,
     "delivery_date":{  
        "date":"2017-01-16 00:00:00.000000",
        "timezone_type":3,
        "timezone":"Asia\/Manila"
     },
     "status":"for_delivery",
     "created_at":"2017-01-16 16:36:51",
     "updated_at":"2017-01-16 16:36:51",
     "driver_id":2,
     "vehicle_id":1,
     "orders":[  
        {  
           "id":1,
           "or_number":"adfasdfadfadfasdf",
           "or_date":{  
              "date":"2017-01-16 00:00:00.000000",
              "timezone_type":3,
              "timezone":"Asia\/Manila"
           },
           "status":"for_delivery",
           "code":"PUJrVMXL",
           "created_at":"2017-01-16 16:31:51",
           "updated_at":"2017-01-16 16:36:51",
           "customer_id":3,
           "delivery_id":1,
           "address":"Mintal, Davao City, Davao Region, Philippines",
           "latitude":"7.0853758",
           "longitude":"125.4864085",
           "customer":{  
              "id":3,
              "first_name":"Lexi",
              "middle_name":"",
              "last_name":"Bell",
              "avatar":"",
              "email":"customer@email.com",
              "username":"customer",
              "created_at":"2017-01-15 16:15:13",
              "updated_at":"2017-01-15 16:15:13",
              "address":"",
              "latitude":null,
              "longitude":null
           }
        },
        {  
           "id":2,
           "or_number":"asdfdddf",
           "or_date":{  
              "date":"2017-01-16 00:00:00.000000",
              "timezone_type":3,
              "timezone":"Asia\/Manila"
           },
           "status":"for_delivery",
           "code":"8UTsyNYd",
           "created_at":"2017-01-16 16:32:26",
           "updated_at":"2017-01-16 16:36:51",
           "customer_id":4,
           "delivery_id":1,
           "address":"Toril, Davao City, Davao Region, Philippines",
           "latitude":"7.0149514",
           "longitude":"125.4978745",
           "customer":{  
              "id":4,
              "first_name":"Yuki",
              "middle_name":"",
              "last_name":"Nagato",
              "avatar":"",
              "email":"yuki@email.com",
              "username":"yuki",
              "created_at":"2017-01-15 16:15:13",
              "updated_at":"2017-01-15 16:15:13",
              "address":"",
              "latitude":null,
              "longitude":null
           }
        }
     ],
     "driver":{  
        "id":2,
        "first_name":"Mia",
        "middle_name":"",
        "last_name":"Khalifa",
        "avatar":"",
        "email":"driver@email.com",
        "username":"driver",
        "created_at":"2017-01-15 16:15:13",
        "updated_at":"2017-01-15 16:15:13",
        "address":"",
        "latitude":null,
        "longitude":null
     },
     "vehicle":{  
        "id":1,
        "plate_number":"VCL 1234",
        "model":"VCL 1234",
        "max_cargo_weight":"100.00",
        "status":"available",
        "created_at":"2017-01-16 16:30:19",
        "updated_at":"2017-01-16 16:30:19"
     }
  }
]
```

**This is my code :**

```
 var client = new RestClient("");
 var request = new RestRequest("delivery", Method.GET);
     request.AddParameter("token", token);

 IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

 mDeliveries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Delivery>>(response.Content);
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.  If you upload it to http://jsonlint.com/ you will get an `Error: Parse error on line 1`.  Are you missing outer curly braces -- `{` and `}` ?

Comment: Also, you tagged this [tag:java] as well as [tag:c#].  Isn't this just c# with no Java?  If Java is not involved the tag should be removed.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging for an explanation of how to tag.